# How do I re-upload a presentation on SlideShare?

Tags: upload, slideshare

Up until a few days ago, there were options to re-upload my SlideShare presentations, but now they seem to have disappeared.  The SlideShare documentation still describes the way that I used to do it, but no such option seems to exist on my account, i.e., no re-upload button to push.

Did I accidentally change my account settings?

Did SlideShare change its options?

Is there a problem with SlideShare?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 14):

I've had a response from Slideshare/LinkedIn support for this issue - spotted the thread when looking for alternate solutions.

> Thank you for your email and I am sorry for any inconvenience this may
>   have caused. We're always looking for ways to improve the SlideShare
>   experience for our members. This sometimes means removing features
>   that aren’t heavily used to invest in others that offer greater value.
>   Please know we continuously evaluate how features and products are
>   used, and make adjustments accordingly to focus our resources on
>   providing the most value to our members.
>
> As a result, we have removed the ability to re-upload documents to
>   SlideShare.   As a workaround, you can upload a new file to SlideShare
>   and delete the current one. Please be aware that this means we will
>   not be able to transfer any views/likes/URL's to the new presentation.
>   Again, I apologize for the inconvenience and we greatly appreciate
>   your feedback. We have documented the issue in order to track
>   additional reports of the problem and for consideration to be
>   addressed in a future release. If there's anything else I can help you
>   with, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Or put in other terms, "we don't give a damn". I can understand changes being made, but this seems arbitrary and no notice has been given.

I'd just uploaded a draft presentation for a talk I'm giving later in the week, so I can get some printing done and have the right URL ... except now that URL is incorrect and of course because the printing has already been completed, I'm going to have to pay for the whole print run again.

Comment: From a suggested edit that should have been a comment: the issue in the last paragraph can be remedied by using a URL redirect service that allows you to change the target (some shorteners allow this), or setting up own redirect, if you own a domain. The redirect/shortened URL would be the one included in print.

Comment: Thanks for share, I will give up to find the re-upload feature on slideshare.